# CloseShieldInputStream vs NoCloseInputStream

Tags: java, inputstream, apache-commons-io

Is there a difference between Apache Commons' [`CloseShieldInputStream`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/input/CloseShieldInputStream.html) and Sun's [`NoCloseInputStream`](https://jax-ws.java.net/nonav/jax-ws-20-fcs/arch/com/sun/xml/ws/util/NoCloseInputStream.html)?  <sub>(Actually in my JDK I have `com.sun.xml.internal.ws.util.NoCloseInputStream` but no `com.sun.xml.ws.util.NoCloseInputStream`)</sub>

From documentation:

> `CloseShieldInputStream` - proxy stream that prevents the underlying input stream from being
>   closed.
>
> ---
>
> `NoCloseInputStream` - `InputStream` that cannot be closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a subtle difference:

1. [`CloseShieldInputStream`](http://grepcode.com/file_/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-io/commons-io/2.0.1/org/apache/commons/io/input/CloseShieldInputStream.java/?v=source): When the `close` method is called, the reference to the originally proxied `InputStream` is removed and replaced by a [no-op implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-io/commons-io/2.1/org/apache/commons/io/input/ClosedInputStream.java). After closing a stream, it is therefore no longer accessible but only exposes the no-op stream. The original stream is however never closed.
2. [`NoCloseInputStream`](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/com/sun/xml/internal/ws/util/NoCloseInputStream.java/?v=source): The `close` method is overridden to do nothing, i.e. not to call the proxied `InputStream`. After a stream is presumably "closed", it can therefore be used as if `close` was never called. The added method `doClose` does however still expose the original closing functionality.

There is no difference between the two versions of the `NoCloseInputStream` other than that the `internal` one is not supposed to be used as it is considered to be internal to Sun's JAX-WS implementation. This internal implementation was later moved to make it public API which is why the package name changed.

Comment: So with `CloseShieldInputStream` you can close the stream only once (then it becomes unreadable, but not closed), and with `NoCloseInputStream` you can close the stream many times (and it remains open) ?

Comment: No, the `CloseShieldInputStream` never closes the original stream. It only removes its wrapped stream reference and therefore hides the original stream after the `CloseShieldInputStream` was closed. It does however never delegate the closing.